# kohana - help with has_many

Tags: php, kohana, relationship, kohana-orm

I'm using kohana 3.2 and I need help with has_many relationship. I cant make my code working. 
This is how my db looks

```
films
-id (pk)
-title
-description

sources
-id (pk)
-film_id
-code

class Model_Film extends ORM
{        
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'sources' => array()
    );

}

class Model_Source extends ORM
{     
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'film'  => array(),
    );
}
```

Source is a link to movie (eg. dvdrip, rmvb)
and here is what i need to do:

```
$film = ORM::factory('film');

$film->title = $title;
$film->description = $desc;
$film->year = $year;
$film->user_id = $uid;
$film->save();

$film->sources->film_id = $film->id;  //last film id
$film->sources->name = $src_name;
$film->sources->code = $src_code;
$film->sources->save();
```

This only adds values for film table, but for sources it makes new empty record.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new source for each one you want to add to the film. For example:

```
$source = ORM::factory('source');
$source->film_id = $film->id;
$source->name = $src_name;
$source->code = $src_code;
$source->save();
```

and repeat for each source you'd like to add to the film. The has many relationship for the film is used for retrieving it's sources, for example:

```
$sources = $film->sources->find_all();
foreach($sources as $src)
{
// do something with $src
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. So has_many relationship is ONLY for retrieving data? cant i save/modify data the way i tried?
I'll try ur code tommorow and give feeback if it works.

Comment: You can but only the way Andrew gave you (inside the loop)